# filter topic list in BigQuery sink connector

Tags: regex, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using kafka connect to write data from kafka to BigQuery. I have multiple topics consumed by a single sink connector, that is using regex to filter the topics it consumes, and catch new topics being added (with the same prefix) automatically (~340 topics, ~30 consumers).
I want to edit a sink connector to ignore a specific topic that is catched.
The regex field in the connector configuration is for example:

```
"topics.regex": "sourcename_sourcetype_dataset_(.*)"
```

What i'm looking for is an "except" mechanism. Preferably without altering the regex itself, but that's an acceptable solution (if so, how can I edit it to not include a table named for example `products_history`.

Comment: `"topics.regex": "sourcename_sourcetype_dataset_(?!products_history)(.*)"`?

Comment: it worked, and I've also added an option for multiple negations: sourcename_sourcetype_dataset_(?!(table_name_1)|(table_name_2))(.*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, regex doesn't work well for "all but one thing".

You can try using the Filter transform + negate rule + TopicNameMatches predicate, making all other topics (via `topics` or `topics.regex`) flow through unaltered.

```
"transforms": "HistoryFilter",
"transforms.HistoryFilter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Filter",
"transforms.HistoryFilter.predicate": "IsProductHistory",
"transforms.HistoryFilter.negate": "true",

"predicates": "IsProductHistory",
"predicates.IsProductHistory.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.TopicNameMatches",
"predicates.IsProductHistory.pattern": "sourcename_sourcetype_dataset_products_history"
```

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/filter-ak.html

Comment: Is it possible to add more than one negate rule with this method?

Comment: Yes. Predicates and Transforms can be chained, as mentioned in the docs